# How to get domain name through go_router on flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

Can someone help me find a way of getting full path through go_router? My app support multiple sub domains and I need to know which one was called.

*.domain.com/path

GoRouterState provide me details only for path and nothing for domain or sub domain. How can I get it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think my question is clear enough.
How I'm suppose to get domain or sub domain through Go Router?

Comment: Did you get to achieve this?

Comment: Also looking for this. Did you find any solution?